# [AnyObject]? does not have a member named 'mutableCopy'

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsmutablearray

```
var sortingArray:NSMutableArray?

sortingArray = fetchedResultsController?.fetchedObjects.mutableCopy()
```

I get the error

```
[AnyObject]? does not have a member named 'mutableCopy'
```

How do I pull out a mutable copy?

Comment: try casting it to an NSMutableArray before the .mutableCopy()

Comment: Can you give example in this casting?

Comment: i havent used swift much, but hopefully its like any normal language... so try `((NSMutableArray)fetchedResultsController?.fetchedObjects).mutableCopy()`

Comment: I tried that -- Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by a ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fetchedObjects` property of `NSFetchedResultsController` is defined as `[AnyObject]?` - so you don't have to convert it to `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` - just use it as is.

Since an array in swift is a value type, it is always copied by value and not by reference, which means a copy is created by just assigning to a variable. So in:

```
var sortingArray = fetchedResultsController?.fetchedObjects
```

a copy of `fetchedObjects` will be copied into `sortingArray`.

Comment: [AnyObject] is not identical to 'NSMutableArray'

Comment: @quantumpotato: Probably because you still declare `var sortingArray:NSMutableArray?`. Try copying Antonio's answer directly, it should work.

Comment: Hm, that works. How can I assign it to property though?

Comment: what do you mean? you want to assign to a class/struct property?

Comment: to a variable defined at the top of my file

Comment: variable or class/struct property, you assign the same way - if it's not what you mean, then I haven't caught what you mean